# How to edit source of the index page in Magento

Tags: javascript, cms, admin-panel, optimization

I am a professional PHP developer, it's been like 2-3 days since I am trying to work with magento. My task is to `optimize the index page`. Thing is, I can not edit the **"actual"** source of **index page**. The edit access in **admin panel** is very (very) limited.

For reference, I did check the `admin panel > CMS > Pages > Homepage > Edit source`. But! it only allows me to edit a specific part of actual index page. It only allows me to edit HTML, and that too, only about 50 lines, while I want to optimize all 1000+ lines of actual page.

And if anyone is wondering, I want to optimize page rendering, **javascript** code, external references, and also remove the redundant code.

Comment: Magento loads alot of templates which are showing if you enable template hints. You will need to optimize the templates.